# iOS: How does Keychain maintain application isolation?

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I know that each app has their own Keychain which cannot be accessed by any other apps.  How does iOS enable this "privacy"?

Looking at an example from [KeychainAccess](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess):

```
let keychain = Keychain(service: "com.example.github-token")
keychain["kishikawakatsumi"] = "01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef"
```

What exactly will prevent another app from running this same code and accessing your `kishikawakatsumi` data?

Comment: Did you try watching the WWDC 2016 video on this topic?

Comment: This is simply Sandboxing. But you may share a Keychain using access groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Keychain Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html) documentation of Apple.

> Note: On iPhone, Keychain rights depend on the provisioning profile
>   used to sign your application. Be sure to consistently use the same
>   provisioning profile across different versions of your application.

**Keychain Access Controls**

> **iOS**: iOS gives an application access to only its own keychain items.
>   The keychain access controls discussed in this section do not apply to
>   iOS.